# Trouble creating basic tables

Tags: tables, tabularx, width

I am currently writing my dissertation in LaTeX, ran into a brick wall creating a simple table.

I want it to look similar to this (Quick mockup done in Numbers)

[image: Needed style]

The main issues I'm facing resolve making the table fit the width of the page without the text spanning on line, I have tried in the traditional tabular and tabularx, but can't seem to get anywhere.

Any assistance would be welcome, thanks !

What I currently have:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X}
 \textbf{Date Commencing:} & 9th September 2013 \\
  \textbf{Weeks Objectives} & My objectives for this week are as follows: \\ Investigate potential project ideas Run project ideas by lecturers
\textbf{Progress} & Date Commencing text goes here \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can show what you have tried so far in form of a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: You have `l` and `X` the other way around. Avoid empty lines in `X` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @egreg has already commented, you seem to have inverted the order of the column types `l` and `X`. The following example creates new column types that (a) automatically make everything in the left-hand column **bold** and (b) use ragged-right rather than full justification -- while allowing hyphenation -- for the material in the right-hand column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\bfseries}l}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}b|L@{}}
Week Commencing & 4 March 2014\\
Objectives & \lipsum*[2]\\
Progress & \lipsum*[3]
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}b|L@{}}
Week Commencing & 9th September 2013 \\
Objectives & Investigate potential project ideas \\
& Run project ideas by lecturers\\
Progress & Date Commencing text goes here \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly! Saved me going to Word. Thanks once again Mico!

Comment: When did you transform into Jabba the Hutt?

Comment: @egreg - The transformation has been happening slowly and steadily and became complete only recently, during a brief stopover in Tatooine.

Comment: @Mico: [Midichlorian Rhapsody](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpvlTVgeivU) `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda - Makes me want to return to Tatooine right away and finally impose some real order on those rascally humans!